# BehaviourSubject and CombineLatest - Weird behaviour

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given the following code.

```
EventLoopScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts));

BehaviorSubject<int> subject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);

subject
    .ObserveOn(scheduler)
    .CombineLatest(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler), (x, y) => x)                        
    .Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));

subject.OnNext(1);
```

Why does it print?

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
...
```

Instead of:

```
0
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your output looks really strange. I would say both of them. I guess the output should be:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

**without** `0`. This is because of the first interval value will be produced in 1 second - definitely after you call `subject.OnNext(1);`

The other strage thing `BehaviourSubject<int>` - is it the UK version of the [BehaviorSubject(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229802%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) ? :) If you have your own `BehaviourSubject` implementation, then please extend your question with it.

Comment: what do you mean? when you download reactive extension from the UK you will get `BehaviorSubject` with the UK-adapted name? I guess you have posted a piece of compilable and working code in your question. But my RX assembly does not have `BehaviourSubject` class. So my assumption - you have your own implementation of `BehaviourSubject`. If I'm right, could you please post it?

Comment: Appologies, it should be BehaviorSubject, not sure how the "u" got in there.

Comment: then it is really strage that you have the mix of `0` and `1` in the output. at my side the code works as expected and produces only ones. what version of rx do you use?

Comment: Updated to newer, version, fixed it.